# How do I end my grid of images after a certain amount and add extra pages to scroll through?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling to figure out what this is called, so I can't find any online tutorials for implementing this. I have a grid of images on my graphic design portfolio, but the length is getting out of hand. After a certain amount of rows, I'd like to create multiple pages to scroll through. An example of this is seen at the bottom of this designer's grid: https://risarodil.com/

Does anyone know what this effect is called? I assume it's created using js.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are thinking of pagination. 
An example shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Pagination - Active State</h2>
  <p>Add class .active to let the user know which page he/she is on:</p>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```